# jQuery, check classes against array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class

The title of this question may be misleading, but I could not think of a better way to word it.

Let me get to the point. I am using buttons to filter a table of statuses. If I have button A and button B active, I only want to display A and B, the rest are hidden. Currently I can only have it display either A or B, not both.

```
var aSelected = [];
$(".admin_view #filterTable tr td button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected"); //class to show user button is active
    //Add to array if not in already
    if ($.inArray(this.id,aSelected) == -1) {
        aSelected.push(this.id);
    //Remove from array if button is not active
    } else if ($.inArray(this.id,aSelected) >= 0) {
        aSelected.splice(aSelected.indexOf(this.id), 1);
    }
    //Show all if array is empty
    if (!aSelected.length) {
        $(".admin_view #applicantTable tbody tr").each(function() {
            $(".admin_view #applicantTable tbody tr").removeClass("hidden");
        });
    }
    //This is the section I need help with
    $.map(aSelected, function(a) {
        $(".admin_view #applicantTable tbody tr").not("."+a).addClass("hidden");
        $(".admin_view #applicantTable tbody tr."+a).removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

I need to find a way to compare against the entire array, not against one piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you hide all other elements for *every item* in aSelected, instead of only at the beginning. If you instead first hide everything and then show the elements you want, it should work:

```
//This is the section I need help with
$(".admin_view #applicantTable tbody tr:not(.hidden)").addClass("hidden");
$.map(aSelected, function(a) {
    $(".admin_view #applicantTable tbody tr.hidden."+a).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was simply an issue with my logic. This answer works perfectly, thank you.